# D3.js ( in Coffeescript) show data on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript, data-visualization

I am in the process of creating a bubble chart with D3.js. Now I want it to display a comment in the `<h3 id="comment"></h3>` tag when I click on each bubble.

Here is my data.csv file:

```
name,count,group,comment
apple,5,red,"This is the best apple ever."
grape,10,purple,"Grapes are huge."
banana,8,yellow,"Are these bananas even ripe?"
pineapple,1,yellow,"Great for making juice."
...
```

And in my viz.coffee, I have:

```
  idValue = (d) -> d.name
  textValue = (d) -> d.name
  groupValue = (d) -> d.group
  commentValue= (d) -> d.comment
```

Originally, I use the following code to display the name of the bubble when clicked:

```
  updateActive = (id) ->
    node.classed("bubble-selected", (d) -> id == idValue(d))
    if id.length > 0
      d3.select("#comment").html("<h3>#{id} is selected.</h3>")
    else
      d3.select("#comment").html("<h3>Nothing is selected</h3>")
```

How should I change it, so that when you click on the bubble, the comment displays instead?

I tried:

```
updateActive = (id) ->
        node.classed("bubble-selected", (d) -> id == idValue(d))
        if id.length > 0
          d3.select("#comment").html(d.comment)
        else
          d3.select("#comment").html("<h3>Click on a bubble to read its comment.</h3>")
```

But it doesn't seem to work, because `d` is undefined, which I can see why, but I'm not sure what I should do. Please help.

Comment: Would be great with the code on plunker or likewise, since it is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: @EmilIngerslev you did it! Even without knowing the full code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I'm not completely sure of your code I think this should work:

```
updateActive = (id) ->
  node.classed("bubble-selected", (d) -> id == idValue(d))
  if id
    for x in data when idValue(x) is id
      d3.select("#comment").html(commentValue(x))
  else
    d3.select("#comment").html("<h3>Click on a bubble to read its comment.</h3>")
```

Here `data` is what you supply to d3 through `.data()`.